How to have multiple departments within the same university be in a single line for the affiliations in Springer latex template?
I want to have multiple departments within the same university be on the same line (no line breaks). The line should break with different universities.
Currently, this is how it looks like: (here X & Y are departments within the same university A)
1X, Univ A
2Y, Univ A
3Z, Univ B

To save space, I want it to appear like this:
1X, 2Y, Univ A
3Z, Univ B 

I am very new to latex so I can't give a minimal working example since the springer template uses a sn-jnl.cls file (which is too big to include here). Any idea how I can change this so that I can get the desired format?
Here's a minimal working example (but this will need sn-jnl.cls and sn-mathphys-num.bst files from the Springer journal article template)
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Some Article Title}

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{X}, \orgname{University A}, \orgaddress{\city{New York}, \postcode{110027}, \state{NY}, \country{USA}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Y}, \orgname{University A}, \orgaddress{\city{New York}, \postcode{110027}, \state{NY}, \country{USA}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Z}, \orgname{University B}, \orgaddress{\city{New York}, \postcode{110032}, \state{NY}, \country{USA}}}

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

\maketitle

\end{document}


The output looks like this:

The sn-jnl.cls file has this block of code (line no. 491 - 504)
\g@addto@macro\artauthors{%
    \ifnum\aucount=1%
    \global\@auemailtrue%
    \else%
    \global\@auemailfalse%
    \fi%
    \Authorfont%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \authorsep{#2}\unskip\ifx\@authfrstarg\empty\else\textsuperscript{\smash{{%
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{\edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{\@@affmark}{\jmkRef{\@@affmark}}}%
     \unskip\sep\affnum\let\sep=,}}}}\fi%
    \def\authorsep{{\au@and} }%%% 
    \global\let\sep\@empty\global\let\@corref\@empty%
}}%

where
\def\authorsep{{\au@and} }%%% 

this piece of code can change the separator for the authors.
But I couldn't find any separator for the affiliations. The only relevant code I could find was (line no. 559)
\def\affil{\advance\addcount by 1\@ifstar\@@coraddress\@@address}%



Hi @CarLaTeX I added it now.

Thank you for adding, but - not a LaTeX question - if Second Author has 2 and not 1, why do you want to join 1 and 2 together?

Secondly, if you have to publish on a Springer journal, you have to follow Springer's rules.

@CarLaTeX in the merged format, the numbers are associated with departments. So, if the second author has 2 but not 1, it's still clear, right? The only reason I want to merge departments within the same university is to save space.

@CarLaTeX I think they can reformat it back if they want to do it, but I'd prefer the merged version for my arxiv paper

To achieve what you like you have to modify sn-jnl, I'm sure someone here will help you.
